# External SharePoint Site- Mobile Detect/Redirect

Tags: redirect, sharepoint, mobile, sharepoint-2010

At my company we have an internet-facing SharePoint 2010 site. We will be creating a subsite that will serve as a mobile site (different design, smaller subset of information). When a user hits our homepage from a mobile device, I would like them to be redirected to a page where they can select a link to either view the mobile site, or the full desktop site.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe standard SharePoint mobile detection needs to be enabled for this. I think I can redirect the mobile users to my "choice" page pretty easily with an HttpModule, so that they don't hit the default SP mobile page. But the problem I'm having is that if they choose to go to the full desktop site, if I try to redirect them there in the module, they're just going back to the default SP mobile page.

My question is, is it possible to achieve this in SharePoint? It seems to me that the default mobile detection would be difficult to override the way I want it to happen. Do mobile users only have access to the mobile subsite in this scenario? If anyone needs more information from me, just let me know, I'll provide whatever I can.

(Also, I know it would be better to do a responsive layout, but that decision is out of my hands)

Answer (score 0):

We created an "ismobile" cookie for the session after the redirect.  This allows us to ignore the redirect if the user has this cookie.  In means that they have already been redirected once this session so don't do it again if they hit the desktop page.
We started using this so that the "Show full website" link didn't just bounce the user back to the mobile page